# Schema for azurepipelines-coverage.yml to configure newly released code coverage metrics feature for PR's

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The feature is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-155-update#code-coverage-metrics-and-branch-policy-for-pull-requests)

> You can now see code coverage metrics for changes within the pull request (PR) view. This ensures that you have adequately tested your changes through automated tests. Coverage status will appear as a comment in the PR overview. You can view details of coverage information for every code line that is changed in the file diff view.

However to configure this it requires `azurepipelines-coverage.yml` at the root of the repo, however I cannot find the schema anywhere.

Anyone got any idea? Without being able to configure it, the default code coverage percentage is set to 70% and I cannot seem to disable it.

I have Googled, searched the blog post, searched Microsoft Documentation and Github.

Comment: Seconding this query, I couldn't find anything either. An additional side effect of this feature is an "Azure Pipelines Test Service" user is now posting comments with huge tables into our PRs, a change that has been universally downvoted by the other devs on our team -- we would love to be able to turn this part off (but maybe keep the rest).

Comment: [Developer Community issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/662432/pr-code-coverage-metrics-undocumented-annoying.html) for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
coverage:
  status:
    diff:
      target: 40%
```

Comment: Is the full schema for this file available anywhere?

Comment: @T2PS Seems no related article now.

Comment: I voted for -1 because of the lack of some explanation, just a dump of some text that is somewhat ordered. The information that @justinsaade asked for is already vague enough.

Comment: The full schema isn't available yet, and this [comment](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/668155/view.html) provides a "sample" view, which is basically the same as in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Full schema is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops). To disable it simply add status: off to azurepipelines-coverage.yml file.