# Coverage status check failed?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I committed the changes to the pull request and yt shows

> "Code coverage status failed.".

I have searched a lot, but couldn't find the cause or solution to resolve this.

```
Azure pipeline test service 
Diff coverage check failed.0/70 (0.00 %) changed lines are covered up to update 2. Diff coverage target is 70.00 %.
```

Verification build is successful but the status is showing code coverage has failed.

Comment: possible same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211986/schema-for-azurepipelines-coverage-yml-to-configure-newly-released-code-coverage) on stack?

Answer (score 14):

Create an `azurepipelines-coverage.yml` config file at the root of your repo with any of the following:

```
coverage:
  status: off     #default on
```

> Turning this off will not post any coverage checks and coverage annotations will not appear in the changed files view.

```
coverage:
  status:
    diff:
      target: 30%     default 70%
```

> Target threshold value for diff coverage must be met for a successful coverage status to be posted.

```
coverage:
  status:
    comments: on    #default off
```

> Indicates whether a comment containing coverage details for each code file should be posted in the pull request

[Microsoft Docs; Configuring coverage settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops#configuring-coverage-settings)

Comment: How is this doable for the old school UI version of the builds? We have turned the condition off, yet it still reports the error on PRs.

Answer (score 2):

Desired coverage thresholds can be defined in an azurepipelines-coverage.yml settings file that is checked in at the root of the repo:

```
coverage:
  status:
    diff:
      target: 40%
```

Comment: Is this file covered anywhere in the Azure Pipelines documentation?

Comment: @PhilipPittle Seems no.

Comment: Hi @starianchen-MSFT, Thanks for reply to my question. Actually i need to know why it is shown in my pull request. I didn't add any configuration as status to my pull request However it shown.Is any recent release(ON july 22 nd) included auto adding of status in pull request?.Azure pipeline test service is shown based on status in pull request or any other?

Comment: @prasanthi It is the new feature https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-155-update#code-coverage-metrics-and-branch-policy-for-pull-requests. But seems that there isn't a way to disable it.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT any update on when documentation for that file will be made available?

Comment: Hi @starianchen-MSFT, Thanks for reply. But i got this configuration status add to only one repostiory pull request . I doesn't added to remaining repository pull request.May i know the reason

Comment: @prasanthi Is there code coverage result in the related build?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT yes code coverage is added in build.

Comment: @prasanthi Do you mean there isn't code coverage analysis result in pull request even through there is build (branch policy) has code coverage result?

Comment: The annoying this about this new service is that it includes the Test projects themselves in the results (saying that they are not covered), even if adding an `[assembly: ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` to the project. It would be really nice if we had a way to exclude or use our own RunSettings/Coverage setup. Maybe we do.... but nothing is documented.. @starianchen-MSFT any update on where the schema is for this file?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 There is no schema now.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT could you explain what your example means? Does it mean the difference between the last coverage? Or is "diff" a misnomer?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I think it is based on the last merged version.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, it appears that you can exclude assemblies. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/customizing-code-coverage-analysis?view=vs-2022

Answer (score -2):

As other people have mentioned you can configure the coverage status check via azurepipelines-coverage.yml file. Full schema is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops).